# Statistical Dependency Transitivity

Tags: statistics, independence

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581649/is-statistical-dependence-transitive) question here on Stack Exchange, and it didn't address something that I then became curious about. If $X_1, X_2$ are dependent and $X_2, X_3$ are dependent, then are $X_1, X_3$ dependent?

Comment: In the first example given my answer, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent, as are $X_2$ and $X_3$, but $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent. Verifications of the dependence/independence were not given, but they are straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $X_1$ and $X_3$ independent random variables, and $X_2=X_1+X_3$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't see that the first scenario in the given link satisfied this. Look on at the first scenario [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581649/is-statistical-dependence-transitive) for the answer :) 
Thanks @André!